# Read and extract information from 3 files (python)

Tags: python

I'am designing a code in python for extract information from a xml file with a function with two variables. The code is working with one file:

```
import re
def Readfiles(XFile):
    Id=''
    des=''
    with open(XFile,"r",encoding="utf-8") as h:
        for line in h:
            wline = line.rstrip("\n")
     
            if re.search("^ID\s{3}",wline):
                res=re.search(r"^ID\s{3}",wline)
                Id=res.group(1)
                  
            if re.search("^DE\s{3}",wline):
                res=re.search("^DE\s{3}",wline)
                des=res.group(1) 
        
    return(Id,des)

(Identificator,desc)=Readfiles("rte.xml", "pre.xml", "ytl.xml")

print("Nom:",Identificator)
print("Descrip:",desc)
```

On the other hand, I want to read more files (tree xml in the code) in a same time but it give me error.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Read yourself : you're telling us "I have a problem, with some code and some file". How can we help ? Also for XML use a parser, try to not use regex

Comment: Why do you expect your function to take three arguments when you've defined it as taking only one? Also note that the values of `Id` and `des` are overwritten every time the pattern is found in a line. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: The code is fine with one file, but when I try to read 3 files at same time, it don't function.

Comment: I want to take information from 3 different files for concatenate after them.

Comment: Seems you should go back a step and read the first chapters in the tutorial again. You defined a function with one parameter. Now you try to call the function with three parameters. That can't work. There are no magical "do what I mean"-elves who handle that for you. Either provide a list with filenames and rewrite your function to work with the list or call the function three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for f in ("rte.xml", "pre.xml", "ytl.xml"):
    (Identificator,desc)=Readfiles(f)
```

The error is that `Readfiles` is called with three arguments but it has only one parameter.